# How to insert a bundle to Google Glass in playground?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I have been trying to create a bundle of cards in https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground without success, here is what I did:

1. insert a card with the following json:

   ```
   {
       "text": "Cover",
       "bundleId": "123",
       "isBundleCover": true,
       "notification": {
           "level": "DEFAULT"
       }
   }
   ```
2. then insert a 2nd card with the following json:

   ```
   {
       "text": "Card 1","bundleId": "123","notification": {
           "level": "DEFAULT"
       }
   }
   ```

But they don't appear to be threaded in my timeline under playground. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the usage information at https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground

> Note: The Playground does not support bundles.

Your card json looks to be correct though, so it should show up correctly on Glass.

Comment: thanks a million - didn't notice that hidden note...!